# I have deleted Firebase Hosting but in my domain still showing that "Site Not Found" under firebase logo from my site?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'd took hosting and domain from the firebase but after i was getting some issues so i deleted hosting and domain then i was getting the message in my domain that "site not found" under firebase logo , so after i'd tried to delete my domain using npm using this cmd (' firebase hosting:disable --project yoursitename ') but it was still showing the same thing that "site not found" please help me out to delete my domain.

site link :- [https://kishandhruv.web.app](https://stackoverflow.com)

So after i'd tried to delete my domain using npm using this cmd (' firebase hosting:disable --project yoursitename ') but it was still showing the same thing that "site not found" please help me out to delete my domain.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that's different than what you observe?  It sounds like your site has been disabled well enough.  If you're unhappy with the result, maybe [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to understand if there is a problem.

Comment: when you run this command: firebase hosting:disable --project yoursitenameit will disable your website, and once any website is disabled, it will show a "site not found" error message, That's how firebase hosting works. you can't delete the subdomain provided by firebase: kishandhruv.web.app.